# Is there a plugin to merge several drafts into a new post?

Tags: plugins, draft

I want to save drafts throught the week, and then publish them in a new post called something like `week news`. ¿How could I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I've done it and explained in a blog post: http://eliasgomez.pro/articulos/merge-posts-he-hecho-plugin-fusionar-entradas-wordpress/